# Does proportionality include addition? ie. if A + B = C are A & B inversely proportional?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

If A×B=C, then A is directly proportional to C in case that B is a constant

or A and B are inversely proportional in case that C is a constant

If A + B = C

If C is a constant are A & B considered inversely proportional (in case that A & B always have a positive value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ are proportional if $kA = B$ for some constant $k$.

$A$ and $B$ are inversely proportional if $AB = k$ for some constant $k$.